# Why does Keras' Model() have an inputs parameter?

Tags: keras

In every single example of Keras' [Functional API documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/), when building a model with `Model()`, the `inputs` parameter seems redundant: it can be deduced from the steps that lead to the construction of the `outputs`. Why does this `inputs` parameter seem necessary, then?

One guess is that otherwise there can be questions about the *order* in which the inputs should be taken (especially when looking at multiple outputs). The (order of the) inputs could however be defined through some convention, but describing this convention would be more cumbersome than asking the user to manually re-inject the inputs of the `outputs`?

That's only a guess: maybe there are some more fundamental reasons to ask the user to include redundant information even in cases like all those of the [Functional API documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)?